# could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0

Tags: android, firebase

After following the somewhat inconsistent instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#name_your_project) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk) I get an error when performing a gradle sync saying `could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0`

Any ideas to why this is happening?

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId ... 
        }

        paid {
            applicationId ... 
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'

    freeCompile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    freeCompile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0:9.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

root/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: How is this question a duplicate if it was asked before the other one?

Comment: Because the other one has more (and higher-upvoted) answers.

Comment: And that is most likely due to the fact that this was marked as duplicate.

Comment: Adding Firebase is now Very easy refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41564507/5996106

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First, you need to update `Play Services Library` to rev.30:

[image]

and then you have a little issue in this line:

```
freeCompile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0:9.0.0'
```

you probably need to correct it to this:

```
freeCompile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0'
```

Comment: You also have to install the Google Repository.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was missing the play services. You were also right about the firebase correction. It seems that the official docs contain an error.

Comment: i have updated all my library but still getting error.

Comment: How do you get to the SDK manager? I think I'm viewing it in Android studio but mine looks very different. Also no option for the Google Repository?!