# Cannot find symbol "messaging" in com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to access FirebaseMessagingService using firebase 9.2.1 library. I have successfully created a project then download the JSON file. I have finally integrated this JSON file with my project. FirebaseInstanceIDService is running fine but showing error with FirebaseMessagingService. So i checked my project folder inside android studio. Then i find that firebase-messaging 9.2.1 library is missing. How can i resolve this issue. I have already upgraded all of the SDK libraries. Please help me to fix this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use screenshots, please. Copy your Gradle section into the question

Comment: Adding Firebase is now Very easy refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41564507/5996106

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to add Firebase Messaging to your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
```

Setup for Firebase Cloud Messaging is explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).

Comment: Also note that you don't need to explicitly depend on firebase-core

Comment: Thanks, buddy! But I already had 
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
dependency in my project. Then why was it showing an error? Why did the error go away when I added your dependency. Thanks.

Comment: @prasang7 FCM needed these two firebase core and firebase-messaging dependency to implement PN. If you want to use other firebase services you need to add another firebase dependency. thanks