# can not resove symbol FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to extends FirebaseMessagingService base class but it unable to import.Please find the build.gradle(project) and build.gradle(app)

`dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}`

```
dependencies {compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find symbol "messaging" in com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631572/cannot-find-symbol-messaging-in-com-google-firebase-messaging-firebasemessagin)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` this line and add outside of dependency

Comment: if i add outside also problem was not resolved @Hulk

Comment: Same issue is coming?

Comment: Can you paste complete grade file here

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'        
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
```

below this line:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
```