# com.firebase:firebase-client-android: VS com.google.firebase:firebase-core

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Today meet some problem where I need to know the detailed difference between

`compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'`

**and**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
```

*Don't make attention to versions*

So please share your knowledge.

Comment: call `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.firebase:firebase-client-android` is legacy. THEY ARE DEPRECATED AS OF MAY 18, 2016.

`com.google.firebase:firebase-core` is current

You can check it [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html)

Also if you want to know the differrent beetween theme you can check 2 docs
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/

Comment: The only difference is that the one is depricated? Or there will be some compile difference between them too? Thanks in adnvance

Comment: the one is depricated and also there are some difference between them. for future you need to move to `com.google.firebase:firebase-core`

Comment: @PhanVanLinh Tried it to the letter and I'm still getting "cannot resolve symbol firebase". My gradle I have: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2' and its still not working

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that **the first one is deprecated**, the first one it is know as firebase 2.X.X and the firebase 3.X.X update use this dependencie *compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'*.

In this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) you can check what you need to install last *Firebase SDK* and their libraries. Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

If you need Firebase Client:

Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(com.firebase.client.Logger.Level.DEBUG);

You need the firebase client library:

```
dependencies {

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```