# FCM database error at the time of compiling dependecies

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I am trying to work with FCM, but I am facing a problem compiling the dependency file. It gives an error like **Under Gradle(Module:app)**:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

**Error**

```
Error:
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1    

Error:(22, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1
```

Please tell me the reason why can't it compile successfully.

Comment: @AL how can i add the code with my selection.

Comment: @AL like if i want to add java file how can add that

Comment: can u add this too and try    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

Comment: Are you using android studio 2.0 ?

Comment: Did you added your Google services file to your app?

Comment: Yes i can @FranciscoDurdinGarcia

Comment: Always keep your android tools up to date.  In Android Studio, use the Check for Updates menu option to keep everything up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Android Studio 2.0** or above, you can simply add firebase dependencies to `Gradle` by following simple steps given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41564507/5996106).
.Following these steps will automatically sync `Gradle` with latest `Firebase` dependencies.

Comment: Then you should try above. Let Android studio do the Gradle sync work .