# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2 for phone number authentication

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication, build.gradle

I've updated my sdk, google play services and google repository, but still this error happened. Please help, I want to integrate authentication using phone number, which is introduced in firebase-auth:11.0.0 , When downgrading to firebase-auth:10.0.0, everything becomes fine.

App level: Build.Gradle

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/module
return
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build.gradle Module:App

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.*****"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: and this dependency and check if it runs `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'` and follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666263/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-firebase)

Comment: still error exist after adding this line

Comment: i've solved this issue, as i've another folder of sdk in my sdk folder. My mistake is that i'm using sdk with different path in my android studio and update other sdk using sdk manager. I know that's silly. But this issue is solved by correcting path of sdk. Thanks to all of you guys.