# Can't resolve symbol FirebaseInstanceIdService while extending a class from it. [error]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am extending a class MyFirebaseIdService from FirebaseInstanceIdService which generate error "*Can't Resolve Symbol FirebaseInstanceIdService*".

I've declare service in AndroidManifest.xml

Service name is also generating error

"*com.asad.chatapp.Notifications.MyFirebaseIdService is not assignable to 
 android.app.service 
Inspection Info: Validates resource references inside xml files*"

Class code :

```
public class MyFirebaseIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    String refreshToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    if (firebaseUser != null){
        updateToken(refreshToken);
    }
}
```

Service code:

```
<service android:name="com.asad.chatapp.Notifications.MyFirebaseIdService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666263/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbol-firebase

Comment: Please the content of your build.gradle file. Please also responde with @AlexMamo